# How do I correctly uninstall a broken installation of Docker and how to reinstall it? (which packages are needed/which not)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, docker, docker-compose

how do I uninstall a broken Docker installation absolutely clean such that I can start a proper re-installation?

OS is Kubuntu 20.04

Obviously I had at least some components (docker swarm) installed with snap. And obviously another installation with apt. I don't know how or why.

I am not knowledgeable with the available packages, which is why I also ask about the re-installation strategy.

I have uninstalled the snap installation of docker by this receipt:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876116/how-to-remove-a-snap-application-docker-completely
But obviously there is still another installation as I witnessed following these instructions in order to install the `docker-ce` community edition:

https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-install-and-start-using-docker-on-ubuntu-20-04

I tried `sudo systemctl status docker` before `sudo apt install docker-ce` and it showed a running docker daemon.

(how to format the quote correctly with breaks?)

> $ sudo systemctl status docker
> ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-31 19:27:27 CEST; 2 days ago
> TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
> Docs: https://docs.docker.com
> Main PID: 2746 (dockerd)
> Tasks: 14
> Memory: 109.9M
> CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
> └─2746 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

But this installation seems to be **broken** because when I run `docker run hello-world` I get the message

> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

despite the output of `sudo systemctl status docker` !

So I first ask myself:
First: Which deinstallation strategy to follow?
Second: What is the right way to install Docker if I don't want Docker Desktop ?

I would like to ask you if you would be so friendly to tell me

1. Should I follow this deinstallation strategy (adding the installed docker-ce to the list to be uninstalled):
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-old-versions
   or
2. rather purge with this one
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine

There seems to be a caveat because the lists of packages mentioned to be uninstalled differ. The first list of packages to be removed is:
`sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`

whereas the second:
`sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin`

If following either strategy, should I add those lists together?

3. Should I follow neither deinstallation strategy but another?

And then if I have uninstalled docker, what are the correct packages to install and how to add docker-compose to the list of binaries? I have read about docker-ce, docker.io ... Also there is docker-engine ? Please tell me which package(s) I must install when I don't want Docker Desktop as stated above and if I want to use docker-compose and possibly docker-swarm.

Thanks !